# Download file from server using php script. File can not be downloaded

Tags: php

Help me please!

I'm trying to download the file using script from remote server. Script starts downloading, but hangs (in chrome shows "starting" and hangs).(I installed MAMP locally and tried to download file from local server and it's works fine.)

Maybe there are wrong configurations in php.ini file?

The script i'm using:

```
   <?php

   $url = "http://cs4-2v4.vk.me/p22/fbb2ec25fb8f67.mp3";

   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=music.mp3");

   ob_flush();
   flush();

   $fp = fopen($url, "rb");
   while (!feof($fp))
   {
       print(fread($fp,8192));
       ob_flush();
       flush();
   }
   fclose($fp);
   ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your script looks really strange for a number of reasons. Why are you assigning `$url` a value from `$_GET` when you then reassign it with an absolute url? Shouldn't you call `ob_start()` first of all, also there is no need to use `ob_flush()` until the entire file is read? I don't see any error checking, can you verify that the file is opened correctly?

Comment: Sorry. Mistakes after "copy-paste"

Comment: Thanks! Tried, but nothing has changed.

Comment: To use an url like you do above you should also make sure so that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your `php.ini`. Since the code works locally but not on the remote server my guess would be that this is the problem.

Comment: You should also enable error reporting to get a descriptive message if anything goes wrong, put `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name = '1353.zip';
$file_url = 'http://download.krizna.com/' . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded.

The error was that the file does not exist with this link (file_exists($path) not works for url's). On the local server everything worked because the request came from the same IP address, from under which user has been registered in a social network vk.com.